# iOS Build not working on fastlane and Github Action

Tags: ios, react-native, github-actions, fastlane

I have a problem with the github Actions CI of the iOS application (react native), I have all the lanes that work well, except the build of the application that works well locally and on Travis, but on Github Actions it remains blocked at the

```
Running script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'
Running script 'Run Script'
```

I removed `Running script 'Run Script'`, and it gets stuck on the step just before!

I have tried a lot of build methods and still don't work!

Here is what I tried as a lane

```
build_app(workspace: "myapp.xcworkspace", scheme: "myapp")
```

and / or

```
gym(
  workspace: "myapp.xcworkspace", 
  configuration: "Release",
  scheme: "myapp",
  clean: true,
  export_method: "ad-hoc"
)
```

[image]

Comment: After days of research I found a solution that works pretty well for me !
before calling `build_app` must call `setup_ci(force: true)` in your `Fastfile`